# Teradata - Merge update with condition

Tags: teradata

I built a query with "merge when matched then". However, I would like to update only the lines showing a change in the fields and not touch the identical lines.
I want to do this because I have a dt_update field equal to current_date.
I found a syntax for SQL SERVER but nothing for teradata: WHEN MATCHED AND **"CONDITION"**:

```
MERGE Locations T
USING Locations_stage S ON T.LocationID=S.LocationID
WHEN MATCHED AND T.LocationID =3 THEN
DELETE 
WHEN MATCHED AND T.LocationID =1 THEN
UPDATE SET LocationName=S.LocationName;
```

Can you help me ?

Thx
Guillaume.

Comment: Thissyntax doesn't exist in Teradata

Comment: It appears the code is simply an example for the "other database syntax" you found and not an attempted solution? Teradata does not support the `WHEN MATCHED AND ...` syntax. But as long as your alternative is "no action", you can have secondary `ON` conditions for the match, in addition to the primary equality conditions on PI/PPI columns.